# Combine column indices based on condition on column values

Tags: python, pandas

I face a problem of combining the column indices into a new column based on the column values.

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   all
0   0   0   4   5   0   0   [2,3]
1   0   2   0   0   0   1   [1,5]
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   []
3   3   0   0   4   5   0   [0,3,4]
4   0   0   0   0   1   0   [4]
```

I got columns 0 to 5 and would like to create the column 'all' based on non-zero values in the column.
I am able to colmbine indices based on the code below. But my effort to attach a condition failed. Please help.

```
Xtrn['all'] = Xtrn.apply(lambda row: ','.join(row.index.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need joined values by separator use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with boolean mask by [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) for greater values like `0` with columns names:

```
Xtrn['all'] = Xtrn.gt(0).dot(Xtrn.columns.astype(str) + ',').str[:-1]
print (Xtrn)
   0  1  2  3  4  5    all
0  0  0  4  5  0  0    2,3
1  0  2  0  0  0  1    1,5
2  0  0  0  0  0  0       
3  3  0  0  4  5  0  0,3,4
4  0  0  0  0  1  0      4
```

Or:

```
Xtrn['all'] = Xtrn.gt(0).dot(Xtrn.columns.astype(str) + ',').str.rstrip(',')
```

If need lists use list comprehension with indexing:

```
cols = Xtrn.columns.to_numpy()
Xtrn['all'] = [cols[x].tolist() for x in Xtrn.gt(0).to_numpy()]
print (Xtrn)
   0  1  2  3  4  5        all
0  0  0  4  5  0  0     [2, 3]
1  0  2  0  0  0  1     [1, 5]
2  0  0  0  0  0  0         []
3  3  0  0  4  5  0  [0, 3, 4]
4  0  0  0  0  1  0        [4]
```

---

`Apply` solutions are possible, but slow, so not recommneded if many rows or if performance is important:

```
Xtrn['all'] = Xtrn.gt(0).apply(lambda row: ','.join(row.index[row].astype(str)), axis=1)

Xtrn['all'] = Xtrn.gt(0).apply(lambda row: row.index[row].tolist(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `enumerate` to get indices like,

```
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  0  4  5  0  0
1  0  2  0  0  0  1
2  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  3  0  0  4  5  0
>>> 
>>> 
>>> df['all'] = df.apply(lambda x: [idx for idx,v in enumerate(x) if v > 0], axis=1)
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4  5        all
0  0  0  4  5  0  0     [2, 3]
1  0  2  0  0  0  1     [1, 5]
2  0  0  0  0  0  0         []
3  3  0  0  4  5  0  [0, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something different

```
df.apply(lambda x : x.index[x > 0].tolist(), axis=1)
Out[316]: 
0       [2, 3]
1       [1, 5]
2           []
3    [0, 3, 4]
4          [4]
dtype: object
```